# "rosmake teleop_base" couldn't find dependency [joy] of [teleop_base]

Tags: ros, teleop-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am using diamondback-full-desktop ROS version on Ubuntu 10.10. I was trying to run this command
$rosmake teleop_base
and it says that [rospack] couldn't find dependency [joy] of [teleop_base].

Is not [joy] a part of diamondback-full-desktop or do I need to install it separately? [I have control_toolbox -which is one dependency of teleop_base]

Thanks
VN

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10610/%22rosmake-teleop_base%22-couldn%27t-find-dependency-%5Bjoy%5D-of-%5Bteleop_base%5D/) by [VN](https://answers.ros.org/users/841/vn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 373 on 2011-07-15

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`joy` is part of the [joystick_drivers](http://www.ros.org/wiki/joystick_drivers) stack. I don't think it's part of the `ros-diamondback-desktop-full` metapackage.

You can install it from binaries using

```
sudo apt-get install ros-diamondback-joystick-drivers
```

---

Originally posted by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) with karma: 4954 on 2011-07-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6